# Why is the PHP get_headers() Last-Modified different from the apache file info

Tags: php, apache, last-modified, get-headers

I have an Apache directory listing of files on a remote server (in Australia/Adelaide +930) I have no control over. This server shows the correct last modified date of a file as: 14-Aug-2009 09:41

I have a PHP script on my US server to check the date of the remote file. `get_headers()['Last-Modified']` returns: Fri, 14 Aug 2009 00:11:11 GMT

How do I get my PHP script to output the same as Apache?

Comment: What are the locale and timezone settings for your server?

Comment: I ask, because they probably are the same time. PHP is giving your UTC, while apache is probably giving you your time adjusted for your timezone. Like, 0800 UTC == 0300 EST (for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in Adelaide, Australia, which is GMT +9:30. `get_headers()` is giving you GMT time. apache is giving you local time.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP headers which returns from `get_headers()` is pushing out GMT time per the HTTP standard. What is your time zone on your server?

Comment: I thought it could be differing server times, but I've added putenv("TZ=Australia/Adelaide"); to no affect